# How can I get dynamic data from within gatsby-config.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Consider the following code within `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-fetch`,
      options: {
        name: `brands`,
        type: `brands`,
        url: `${dynamicURL}`, // This is the part I need to be dynamic at run/build time.
        method: `get`,
        axiosConfig: {
          headers: { Accept: "text/csv" },
        },
        saveTo: `${__dirname}/src/data/brands-summary.csv`,
        createNodes: false,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

As you can see above, the URL for the source plugin is something that I need to be dynamic. The reason for this is that the file URL will *change* every time it's updated in the CMS. I need to query the CMS for that field and get its CDN URL before passing to the plugin.

I tried adding the following to the top of `gatsby-config.js` but I'm getting errors.

```
const axios = require("axios")

let dynamicURL = ""
const getBrands = async () => {
  return await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://some-proxy-url-that-returns-json-with-the-csv-file-url",
  })
}

;(async () => {
  const brands = await getBrands()
  dynamicURL = brands.data.summary.url
})()
```

I'm assuming this doesn't work because the config is not waiting for the request above to resolve and therefore, all we get is a blank URL.

Is there any better way to do this? I can't simply supply the source plugin with a fixed/known URL ahead of time.

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm normally a Vue.js guy but having to work with React/Gatsby and so I'm not entirely familiar with it.

Answer (score 10):

I had similar requirement where I need to set siteId of gatsby-plugin-matomo dynamically by fetching data from async api. After searching a lot of documentation of gatsby build lifecycle, I found a solution.

Here is my approach -

**gatsby-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
   siteMetadata: {
     ...
   },
   plugins: {
     {
        resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-matomo',
        options: {
           siteId: '',
           matomoUrl: 'MATOMO_URL',
           siteUrl: 'GATSBY_SITE_URL',
           dev: true
        }
      }
    }
};
```

Here siteId is blank because I need to put it dynamically.

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onPreInit = async ({ actions, store }) => {
    const { setPluginStatus } = actions;
    const state = store.getState();
    const plugin = state.flattenedPlugins.find(plugin => plugin.name === "gatsby-plugin-matomo");
    if (plugin) {
        const matomo_site_id = await fetchMatomoSiteId('API_ENDPOINT_URL');
        plugin.pluginOptions = {...plugin.pluginOptions, ...{ siteId: matomo_site_id }};
        setPluginStatus({ pluginOptions: plugin.pluginOptions }, plugin);
    }
};

exports.createPages = async function createPages({ actions, graphql }) {
    /* Create page code */
};
```

**onPreInit** is a gatsby lifecycle method which is executing just after plugin loaded from config. onPreInit lifecycle hook has some built in methods.

**store** is the redux store where gatsby is storing all required information for build process.

**setPluginStatus** is a redux action by which plugin data can be modified in redux store of gatsby.

Here the important thing is **onPreInit** lifecycle hook has to be called in async way.

Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: I needed to do that for the google tag manager. I'd like to point out that the line `plugin.pluginOptions = {...plugin.pluginOptions, ...{ siteId: matomo_site_id }};` is non optional. The `plugin.pluginOptions` need to be mutated for it to work. Curiously, `setPluginStatus` can be removed.

Comment: is there any way to hydrate/push to the gatsby store, like if I wanted to simply push the matomo value and have it digestable on other lifecycle hooks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that may work for you is using [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) as you said, the URL is known so, you can add them in a `.env` file rather than a CSV.

By default, Gatsby uses `.env.development` for `gatsby develop` and a `.env.production` for `gatsby build` command. So you will need to create two files in the root of your project.

In your `.env` (both and `.env.development` and `.env.production`) just add:

```
DYNAMIC_URL: https://yourUrl.com
```

Since your `gatsby-config.js` is rendered in your Node server, you don't need to prefix them by `GATSBY_` as the ones rendered in the client-side needs. So, in your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-fetch`,
      options: {
        name: `brands`,
        type: `brands`,
        url: process.env.DYNAMIC_URL, // This is the part I need to be dynamic at run/build time.
        method: `get`,
        axiosConfig: {
          headers: { Accept: "text/csv" },
        },
        saveTo: `${__dirname}/src/data/brands-summary.csv`,
        createNodes: false,
      },
    },
  ],
```

It's important to avoid tracking those files in your Git repository since you don't want to expose this type of data.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I think you've simply shifted the issue over to .env. I'm talking about using the result of an async operation in order to populate this field before the config executes.

Comment: Why do you think you can't put this file under version control (git)?

Comment: You certainly can track those files but ideally they should be managed at infra level since they normally contain sensitive data and ids